# How can I run my main class, and have it see other classes in the same folder using the Atom editor?

Tags: java, atom-editor

I recently started to use atom, and I am confused about how to run my code. I have classes shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4X9gr.png). However, when I run this using the script package that I installed, it provides this error:

```
\Projects\Yahtzee\Main.java:3: error: cannot find symbol  
    Yahtzee y = new Yahtzee();  
    ^  
  symbol:   class Yahtzee  
  location: class Main  
\Projects\Yahtzee\Main.java:3: error: cannot find symbol  
    Yahtzee y = new Yahtzee();  
                    ^  
  symbol:   class Yahtzee  
  location: class Main  
2 errors
[Finished in 0.879s]
```

I copied my code over from where I used to run it, and it worked fine there.

Comment: Try moving your files into the Project folder instead of Yahtzee.  Otherwise, you should declare the package Yahtzee in each of your classes.

Comment: I tried moving them to a project folder and it still did not work. How would I declare Yahtzee in each of my classes? Could you give me an example of how you would do it?